# reading a parsing messages in a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, parsing

Forgive me if the title is a bit vague.  I will try to explain a bit better what i am trying to accomplish.

There is a function called parsebytes that is part of an external interface that i have implemented. It takes an array of bytes and a length.  All parsing in this particular program runs on a single thread so i want to get my data out of parsebytes as quickly as possible so it can return to getting more data off the line.  My methodology in pseudocode is this:
Create an externally running thread (ParserThreadClass).
every time parsebytes is called, put the bytes into a queue in the ParserThreadClass by looping through all the bytes and doing a byteQueue.add(bytes[i]).  This code is surrounded by a synchronized(byteQueue)
That, in effect, should free the parsebytes to go back and get more data.

While that is happening, my ParserThreadClass is also running.  This is the code in the run() function

```
while (!shutdown) //while the thread is still running
    {
        synchronized (byteQueue) 
        {
            bytes.addAll(byteQueue);  //an arraylist
            byteQueue.clear();
        }

        parseMessage();   //this will take the bytes arraylist and build an xml message.
    }
```

Am i being overly inefficient here?  If so, can someone give me an idea of how i should tackle this?

Comment: Think about this: If there's nothing to parse, what does this code do? You need to add sensible `notify`/`wait` semantics.

Comment: The parseMessage() function checks to see if the number of bytes > 4 before continuing.  Should i add that kind of check at the .addAll(byteQueue)?

Comment: What does it do if the number of bytes is less than 4? What alternative does it have to continuing? If it returns, this code will just call it again. How would it stop?

Comment: It just returns out.  The thread is expected to be running while there is a TCP connection.  If there is nothing in the queue, there may be next iteration.

Comment: Yeah, that's horribly broken. You need to use `notify`/`wait` in some kind of sensible way. If you're waiting for the phone to ring, you don't check if the phone is ringing a million times a second. You just wait for it to ring -- in place.

Comment: @mattg's answer is a mostly functional example for using a BlockingQueue.  note, however, that the answer to your "larger question" about efficiency is that _you should profile the application to see which implementation performs the best for you_.  which solution is the "right" one for you depends on your actual program characteristics, and you can only figure that out by actual runtime profiling.

Comment: @jtahlborn: This is a simple enough "mine run" case where you can just use any sane method and it will almost certainly be more than good enough. You just can't do something boneheaded like spinning because then it's near certain you'll have to come back and fix it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - sure, but maybe the parsing is really fast and the whole secondary thread isn't even necessary?  much simpler code in that case...

Comment: @jtahlborn: I agree. That's actually fairly likely. The cost of dispatching to a thread is probably more than the concurrency benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I've tried to solve the problem previously.  Basically you have a producer thread, like you have here, that reads the file and puts items onto the queue.  Then you have a worker thread that reads things from the queue and processes them.  Code is below, but it looks essentially the same as what you're doing.  What I found is that this gives me just about no speed up, because the processing I need to do per line is pretty quick, relative to the disk read.  If the parsing you have to do is pretty intensive, or the chunks are pretty large, you could see some speed up doing it this way.  But if it's pretty minimal, don't expect to see much in the way of performance improvement, because the process is IO bound.  In those situations, you need to parallelize the disk access, which you can't really do on a single machine.

```
public static LinkedBlockingQueue<Pair<String, String>> mappings;
public static final Pair<String, String> end =
    new Pair<String, String>("END", "END");
public static AtomicBoolean done;
public static NpToEntityMapping mapping;
public static Set<String> attested_nps;
public static Set<Entity> possible_entities;

public static class ProducerThread implements Runnable {
    private File f;

    public ProducerThread(File f) {
        this.f = f;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String entities = reader.readLine();
                String np = line.trim();
                mappings.put(new Pair<String, String>(np, entities));
            }
            reader.close();
            for (int i=0; i<num_threads; i++) {
                mappings.put(end);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Producer thread interrupted");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Producer thread threw IOException");
        }
    }
}

public static class WorkerThread implements Runnable {
    private Dictionary dict;
    private EntityFactory factory;

    public WorkerThread(Dictionary dict, EntityFactory factory) {
        this.dict = dict;
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (!done.get()) {
                Pair<String, String> np_ent = mappings.take();
                if (np_ent == end) {
                    done.set(false);
                    continue;
                }
                String entities = np_ent.getRight();
                String np = np_ent.getLeft().toLowerCase();
                if (attested_nps == null || attested_nps.contains(np)) {
                    int np_index = dict.getIndex(np);
                    HashSet<Entity> entity_set = new HashSet<Entity>();
                    for (String entity : entities.split(", ")) {
                        Entity e = factory.createEntity(entity.trim());
                        if (possible_entities != null) {
                            possible_entities.add(e);
                        }
                        entity_set.add(e);
                    }
                    mapping.put(np_index, entity_set);
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Worker thread interrupted");
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Here's code for the main thread that starts the producer and worker threads:

```
    Thread producer = new Thread(new ProducerThread(f), "Producer");
    producer.start();
    ArrayList<Thread> workers = new ArrayList<Thread>();
    for (int i=0; i<num_threads; i++) {
        workers.add(new Thread(new WorkerThread(dict, factory), "Worker"));
    }
    for (Thread t : workers) {
        t.start();
    }
    try {
        producer.join();
        for (Thread t : workers) {
            t.join();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Main thread interrupted...");
    }
```

It should also be fine to have the work done in the producer thread just be done in the main thread, taking out the need to start and join with another thread in the main code.  Be sure to start the worker threads before going through the file, though, and join with them after you've done the work.  I'm not sure about the performance differences between that way and the way I have here, though.

Comment: Some of my messages can be up to 7200 bytes, so they are substantial.  Generally, that isn't true, but the parseMessage() function has a state machine, so i am reading/building byte-by-byte.

Comment: Note that `LinkedBlockingQueue` does the `notify/wait` that David Schwartz was talking about above.  I thought you might have used something similar in your parseMessage() method, which is why I said that this was essentially equivalent to what you're doing.  If you're not, you probably want to be using `LinkedBlockingQueue`.  If you need help writing the method that starts and joins these producer and worker threads, I can show you how to do that, too.

Comment: I'm new to the LBQ.  I'll read up on it and get back to you if i need help.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty close to implementing what i think is correct code for a LBQ.  can you show me the starting/joining code?  

Also - the producer (if i call it that), isn't really a producer in the terms of your example.  The function that reads bytes off the wire is acting as my producer and i am putting the atomic boolean and LBQ vars in that class.  The listener is in another class and refs the vars statically as you defined.  Sound reasonable?

Comment: I edited the original post, and I think I answered your questions.

Comment: actually - one more.  where are you setting your atomicboolean to false?

Comment: note, you don't typically want to use a separate boolean as a "done" flag when working with a BlockingQueue as it's easy to get things out of sync (either ending too soon or not at all).  when working with a BlockingQueue, you want to use the "poison pill" pattern for telling the consumer to finish (a special value which says "you're finished" which _you put on the queue_).

Comment: @jtahlborn - that's why he's using the atomic boolean and referencing it statically.

Comment: @Jason - making it static or atomic doesn't change anything i said.  i wasn't referring to thread visibility issues, i was referring to logic issues.

Comment: @mattg - see question above?

Comment: @jtahlborn - i misread your original.  didn't mattg do that with the "end", "end" check directly after the mappings.take?

Comment: Yeah, I did that with the `end` values; now that I look at it, I would say that @jtahlborn is right, and the `done` variable is redundant (I had initially done it differently, then discovered the right way to do it with the `end` variables.  `done` is just vestigial).  In any event, there was a bug in the code I had up there - it should have been `done.set(false)`, not `done.set(true)`.  I fixed the bug.

Comment: actually, i missed `end` on my first reading.  yes, using something like `end` is the right way to do hit.  however, looking at it now, i have no clue what the point of `done` is or what it is trying to accomplish.  when the worker sees `end`, it should just return (and `done` can be completely removed).

Comment: That's just trial and error, I think.  It depends on how many cores you have available on your machine, and how quickly the producer can get information from the data source to the workers.  If you know how quickly the producer puts tasks into the queue and how long it generally takes to finish items on the queue, you can use some equations from queueing theory to determine how many workers to start.  But it's probably easier to just try it with a few different values and see what happens.